# How do I calculate ip address and gateway for nmtui command in linux?

Tags: networkmanager

Is there any online tool that does this?

I set my ipv4 address as 10.0.0.11.

I set my gateway as 10.0.0.10.

I set my DNS server as 8.8.8.8.

But I am unable to ssh to my server in  VMWare workstation via Mobaxterm.

Thus, I feel like I am miscalculating the values. I  want to learn a way to calculate these values based on some value.

Edit: I think something else is going on.

I did exactly as mentioned in https://systemzone.net/centos-8-networking-configuration-using-nmtui-tool/
This article, but it still didn't work.

```
Network Error: Connection timed out
```

Comment: As others have indicated, you should let DHCP do this if you can. *"my goal is that i want to set static values"*. If you are trying to statically define it yourself then it's still better to let DHCP try first to prove networking works, then reconfigure statically. There's a bunch of things you can do wrong with the VMs networking that we couldn't begin to guess here.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to calculate.

The Gateway is a single address that's part of your subnet, which *your network* defines, not calculates. The DNS server is the address of someone's DNS server (in your case, Google).

So, you can only know the right values, or not know; no tool can "calculate" these.

Comment: so why am I facing the issues?

Comment: @zeeshanseikh you need to explain _in your question_ what issues you're having. But to stay with I'd stop trying to set the values and let you system ask for the correct ones

Comment: my goal is that i want to set static values.

Comment: @zeeshanseikh that changes nothing. Nothing of this is calculated. It's dictated by **your** network, not something you can derive. Hence, letting the network configure these things (through DHCP v4) is usually much much preferable.

Comment: @zeeshanseikh at most the only value you have control of here is the IP you set for your system, but even that must be constrained to the set of available IPs in the network (less the set of IPs used for DHCP). Neither of those, nor the gateway address, are something you calculate - they're already part of the network's configuration